# silverlight expression in binding

Tags: xaml, silverlight, binding

I am styling a usercontrol of mine.

I have some "constants" regarding the size of the object, and in my template object I have something like

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <sys:Double x:Key="width">10</sys:Double>
        <sys:Double x:Key="margin">30</sys:Double>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    ...
    <ControlTemplate ...>
        <Grid x:Name="width_plus_margin">
            ...
```

If I wanted the width of the "witdh_plus_margin" to be "width" value I just added something like

```
Width="{StaticResource width}"
```

but what I really need is to set something like

```
Width="{StaticResource width} + {StaticResource margin}"
```

this syntax is wrong. Is there a way to specify what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to more than one source property in a Binding. Therefore you need some kind of aggregator that offers an output property you can bind against.

Here are some variations of the same pattern:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <sys:Double x:Key="width">10</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double x:Key="margin">30</sys:Double>
    <BindableResult x:Key="widthPlusMargin" ArithmeticOperation="Add" LeftOperand="{StaticResource width}" RightOperand="{StaticResource margin}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid Width="{StaticResource widthPlusMargin}">
```

with BindableResult having an implicit cast operator to double:

```
public static implicit operator double(BindableResult source)
{
    return source.InternalResult;
}
```

or something like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <sys:Double x:Key="width">10</sys:Double>
    <sys:Double x:Key="margin">30</sys:Double>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <SetCombinedWidth Value1="{StaticResource width}" Value2="{StaticResource margin}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

You can also google for *silverlight multibinding implementations* and see if that is more to your taste. But in the end it is just another variation of the aggregator.